# Why is $\nabla f\cdot n$ zero on the boundary

Tags: calculus

> Let $B$ be the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and assume $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and $f$ is constant in a neighborhood of $\partial B$. Show $\int_B (f_{xx}+f_{yy}+f_{zz})dv=0$.

I think you just use divergence theorem, but I'm not sure why $\int_{\partial B}(\nabla f)\cdot\hat{n}ds$ is zero. $\nabla f$ is zero in the neighborhood $f$ is constant in, but why would $(\nabla f)\cdot\hat{n}$ be zero on the entire boundary?

Comment: Hint: what is the derivative of a constant?

Comment: Presumably the boundary is within the neighborhood of itself, and thus $f$ is constant there.

Comment: @SeanRoberson so $f$ must be constant on the entire boundary?

Comment: Ah I see. I guess I was just reading the question wrong. I understood it to mean, "for some $x\in\partial B$, there is a $U\subseteq\partial B$ with $x\in U$ and $f$ constant on $U$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is constant in a neighborhood of $\partial B$, than $\nabla f(x)=0$  and $\nabla f(x)\cdot \vec n=0$, for all points $x\in \partial B$. So the integral is null.

Comment: Thanks Emilio. I think I just misread the question. I thought it meant $f$ is constant on some neigborhood contained in $\partial B$

Comment: In this case the statement is not true in general.